# Smoke in Blender game shows as block

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am  trying out blender Game and I am making an earth smash animation where there
is dust impact in circular  shape .. it works fine but in blender game mode nothing shows but a square block ...
BTW I am using Blender 2.78
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blenders Game Mode does not support smoke simulations. Or Fluids.

Comment: Ok thank you Carsten ..I really thought that I was missing something out.

Comment: @mazenhussien if an answer helped you don't just thank in the comments. Upvote it, or consider marking it as accepted if it solved your problem